# construct pdf in customize format in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, pdf

I'm trying to download a PDF with a button click using jsPDF. I'm facing issues with styling the PDF content and adding images from Blob storage. Currently, I'm using HTML2Canvas, but it captures my view, which is not the desired behavior.

so from here   [check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTUQK.png) i want when i click on download pdf it generates a pdf like this [check image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d4K6.png)

i have all the pdf content just facing issues in constructing this. how can construct my pdf in my desired format ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can use html2pdf
when you click in btn use document.getElementsByTagName or by id to get your div

```
 const element = document.getElementsByTagName('your selector component ')[0];
const options = {
  margin: [12, 5, 12, 5],
  filename: 'fileName',
  image: { type: 'jpeg', quality: 0.98 },
  html2canvas: { dpi: 192, scale: 0.8, letterRendering: true, useCORS: true },
  jsPDF: { unit: 'mm', format: 'a4', orientation: 'portrait' },
  pagebreak: { mode: ['css', 'legacy'] },
};
html2pdf().from(element).set(options).toPdf().save();
```

Comment: but my view is not same as my desired pdf view , if i put display none and make html content of my pdf view then it's not going to download as display none

Comment: no it work perfectly on my code